# "Element type is invalid" Store import error in redux-persist in react native,

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I can't find where the import error could possibly be.  The error is:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.
>
> This error is located at:
> in Provider (at App.js:12)
> in App (created by ExpoRoot)
> ...

**configureStore.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import { campsites } from './campsites';
import { comments } from './comments';
import { promotions } from './promotions';
import { partners } from './partners';
import { favorites } from './favorites'
import { persistStore, persistCombineReducers } from 'redux-persist';
import storage  from 'redux-persist/es/storage'

const config = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    debug: true
}
    export const ConfigureStore = () => {
        const store = createStore(
            persistCombineReducers(config, {
                campsites,
                comments,
                partners,
                promotions,
                favorites
            }),
            applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)
        );
    
        const persistor = persistStore(store)
    
        return { persistor, store };
    };
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Main from './components/MainComponent';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { ConfigureStore } from './redux/configureStore';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist';
import Loading from './components/LoadingComponent'

const { persistor, store } = ConfigureStore();

export default function App() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <PersistGate
                loading={<Loading />}
                persistor={persistor}>
                <Main />
            </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the wrong import on PersistGate.  It should have been:

```
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/es/integration/react';
```